# How to make and simulate cyclic closed circuits in Quartus

Tags: digital-logic, simulation, quartus

I need to simulate this circuit.

[image]

But simulation returns that, prior and hold lines is in 'U' state when they must output something. Prior line must output number and hold line must switch into high logic state.

Even if I just simulate one single block like with hold_out and prior_out connected to hold_in and prior_in accordingly I still get this issue with uninitialized lines state.

I get same result, prior line switch to 'U' state, when it must return some number.

So, is there any solution to simulate circuits like this one?

P.S Schematic of arbitr component. priorCounter and compareNums written on VHDL.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need a reset signal for this circuit, otherwise it may never get into a predictable state. And this is not a simulation-specific or Quartus-specific trick - unknown states affect pretty much any non-trivial circuit with internal memory. All microprocessors have a reset signal exactly for this reason.